# How to read specific parts of a .txt file in JAVA

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to read from a .txt file. I know how to read a whole file, but I am having difficulties reading between two specific points in a file. 
I am also trying to use the scanner class and this is what I have so far:

```
public void readFiles(String fileString)throws FileNotFoundException{

        file = new File(fileString);
        Scanner scanner = null; 
        line=""; 


        //access file
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }


            // if more lines in file, go to next line
           while (scanner.hasNext())
            {
               line = scanner.next();


               if (scanner.equals("BGSTART")) //tag in the txt to locate position
               {
                   line = scanner.nextLine();
                   System.out.println(line);
                   lb1.append(line); //attaches to a JTextArea.
                   window2.add(lb1);//adds to JPanel
                }
            }
```

.txt file looks something like this:

BGSTART
//content
BGEND

Nothing is posted onto the panel when I run the program.

I am trying to read it between those two points.I don't have a lot of experience in reading from txt file. 
Any suggestions?
Thank You.

Comment: Is the token `BGSTART` and `BGEND`always on a separate line?

Comment: Check out `RandomAccessFile`. Here is a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html) about it

Comment: Yes they are on a separate line

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `BGSTART` and `BGEND` are on seperate lines, as per @SubOptimal's question, you would need to do this:

```
boolean tokenFound = false;
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
   line = scanner.nextLine();

   //line, not scanner. 
   if (line.equals("BGSTART")) //tag in the txt to locate position
   {
       tokenFound = true;
   }
   else if (line.equals("BGEND"))
   {
       tokenFound = false;
   }

   if(tokenFound)
   {                   
       System.out.println(line);
       lb1.append(line); //attaches to a JTextArea.
       window2.add(lb1);//adds to JPanel
   }
}
```

Some improvements:

```
try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));

        //Moved the rest of the code within the try block.
        //As it was before, if there where any problems loading the file, you would have gotten an error message (File not found)
        //as per your catch block but you would then have gotten an unhandled null pointer exception when you would have tried to
        //execute this bit: scanner.hasNextLine()
        boolean tokenFound = false;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();

            //line, not scanner.
            if (line.equals("BGSTART")) //tag in the txt to locate position
            {
                tokenFound = true;
            } else if (line.equals("BGEND")) {
                tokenFound = false;
            }

            if ((tokenFound) && (!line.equals("BGSTART"))) {
                System.out.println(line);
               //I am not sure what is happening here.
                //lb1.append(line); //attaches to a JTextArea.
                //window2.add(lb1);//adds to JPanel
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
```

File content:

```
do not show line one
do not show line two
BGSTART 
this is a line
this is another line
this is a third line
BGEND
do not show line three
do not show line four
```

Comment: Your code prints as supposed, but it creates a new line with every word instead of the phrases. I tried changing line to line=scanner.nextLine() but it does not print anything. I also get an exception "java.util.NoSuchElementException" that seems to be on that same line.

Comment: @Varoag: Sorry my bad, I have made some changes, is this how your code is now? (People usually read lines from files, somehow read your `next` calls to `nextLine`...)

Comment: I added the changed code. Now it reads without spaces. Basically the text is one whole line. do you suggest a line splitter?

Comment: @Varoag: To avoid many edits, will your BGSTART and BDEND be on seperate lines without other words?

Comment: also the spaces between the words are omitted as well

Comment: Yes. The fie reads BGSTART. (new line) "line of txt to be printed" (new line) BGEND

Comment: @Varoag: Made some minor changes, see if it helps (changed reading from scanner as `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

Comment: It reacts the same way. I have tried different versions of your code and it does the same thing. Could it be the file?

Comment: @Varoag: I was using `print`, and not `println` (it shows that the end is getting towards the end...` you might also need to change this: `lb1.append(line); //attaches to a JTextArea.` to this: `lb1.append(line + "\n"); //attaches to a JTextArea.`

Comment: I added that . Still skips every word. I am not sure where the problems is. I have to guess that it is not the code. I'll look into the file.

Comment: @Varoag: Sorry for the delay. I'll see if I can get this code running later on in the day.

Comment: @Varoag: I have pasted the code I used to get 3 lines of text with the following: `this is a line
this is another line
this is a third line`. (I got 3 lines in total. If this is not working for you, then the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use substring? once you have located your BGSTART and BGEND you can capture the string between it somewhere in the lines of the below code:

```
 StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        sb.append(line);
 }
String capturedString = sampleString.substring(sb.toString().indexOf("BGSTART"),
          sb.toString().indexOf("BGEND"));
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Almost good, but you are doing:

```
 if (scanner.equals("BGSTART")) //tag in the txt to locate position
```

You should look for file content in `line` variable not `scanner`.
So try this:

```
 if (line.equals("BGSTART")) //tag in the txt to locate position
```